# Codehaus Cargo missing logging subsystem

Tags: maven-cargo, cargo-maven2-plugin

I have an issue with running tests with Codehaus Cargo v18.
Though Wildfly 18.0.1 allows me not to have the logging subsystem in the `standalone.xml` - so I can put all the logging conf in the logging.properties, Cargo v18 fails on deploying when I run it with the `standalone.xml`:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 30-Jul-2020 - 18:06:05,116 ERROR [org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContext#print] {
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "outcome" => "failed",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[(\"subsystem\" => \"logging\")]' not found",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "rolled-back" => true
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] }
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] {
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "outcome" => "failed",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[(\"subsystem\" => \"logging\")]' not found",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "rolled-back" => true
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] }
```

How can I avoid setting up such subsystem module and use the `logging.properties` instead, directly in Cargo?